# Change RadioButton checkstate in event

Tags: vb.net, events, radio-button, vb6-migration

I'm migrating some legacy code from VB6 to VB.NET and I've run into an annoying issue. What's currently happening is the user is provided with `RadionButton` controls to denote hierarchy. When they select a value the code verifies that it's valid (can't have C be the child of A, has to be the child of B) and if it's not it returns the `RadioButton` to the original setting.

The issue is that when the function that does this returns to the event handler it returns the `RadioButton` state to how it was when it was clicked (User clicked C, code returns it to B, when function exits it returns to C firing the event that'll turn it to B again, etc., etc. causing an infinite loop). Is there a way to change which `RadioButton is selected inside a function called by`CheckedChanged` event and have it stick?

I know the better design is to disable the invalid `RadioButton` controls ahead of time, but this is how it's designed and my job is to get it working in a limited time frame, so I'm stuck with bad design now as opposed to good design later.

Code:

```
Private Sub optIndent_2_ClickEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles optIndent_2.CheckedChanged
    optIndent_Click(2, sender.Checked)
End Sub

Private Sub optIndent_3_ClickEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles optIndent_3.CheckedChanged
    optIndent_Click(3, sender.Checked)
    Dim i As Integer = 1
End Sub

Private Sub optIndent_Click(ByRef Index As Short, ByRef value As Short)
    If value = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Index = 2 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Index = 3 Then
        optIndent_2.Checked = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

You'll see that when the code exits `optIndent_Click (3, sender.checked)` the value will transition from false to true, the process will repeat forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the use of [ByRef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/byref):

> Specifies that an argument is passed in such a way that the called procedure can change the value of a variable underlying the argument in the calling code.

Instead you should use [ByVal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/byval):

> Specifies that an argument is passed in such a way that the called procedure or property cannot change the value of a variable underlying the argument in the calling code.

Changing the argument `value` to be a `ByVal` argument will fix the problem. This will stop `value` from retaining its "value".

I appreciate that you're stuck with the bad design so this may not fit into this projects scope but at some point you should look at turning [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement):

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.

This would have highlighted `ByVal value As Short` as being an issue:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Boolean' to 'Short'.

The fix would be; `ByVal value As Boolean`.

Having Option Strict On would also highlight `sender.Checked` as being an error:

> Option Strict On disallows late binding

The fix would be to cast `sender` as a `RadioButton` so you can directly access its properties; `DirectCast(sender, RadioButton).Checked`.

Your code would look something like:

```
Private Sub optIndent_2_ClickEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles optIndent_2.CheckedChanged
    optIndent_Click(2, DirectCast(sender, RadioButton).Checked)
End Sub

Private Sub optIndent_3_ClickEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles optIndent_3.CheckedChanged
    optIndent_Click(3, DirectCast(sender, RadioButton).Checked)
End Sub

Private Sub optIndent_Click(ByVal Index As Short, ByVal value As Boolean)
    If value = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Index = 2 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Index = 3 Then
        optIndent_2.Checked = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```